# The Code Execution Cannot Proceed Because 'Qt5WebEngineCore.dll' Cannot be Found

Tags: python, dll, 64-bit

I am trying to make a python program which requires the 'qt5webenginecore' package, but I need to install the .dll file for qt5webenginecore. I know there are sites that offer .dll files for free but I cannot find a file for a x64 bit system. Can someone help with this?